# LastWriteTime being modified when copying to Dropbox folder

Tags: c#, windows, file, backup, dropbox

I've got a little C# script I use to backup my development folder to my Dropbox folder, comparing the source and target `FileInfo.LastWriteTime` for each file then doing a `File.Copy` if needed.

I've noticed that newly created files are being copied not only on the following run of the script as expected but also on the run after that, despite having not been modified in the interim.

It seems that the LastModifiedDate is being rounded down to the nearest second the first time each file is copied, making it appear older than the original next time. On the next run the files are copied across again but now the LastModifiedDate is not rounded down, even if the file is actually modified, so everything works as expected from then on.

Can anyone shed any light on what's going on here?

**Update:**

Seems to only affect certain file types, .png being one of them. The problem can demonstrated with the following code:

```
var source = @"c:\temp\test.png";
var target = @"C:\Users\Me\Dropbox\test.png";
Console.WriteLine(File.GetLastWriteTime(source).ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
Console.WriteLine(File.GetLastWriteTime(target).ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")); 
File.Copy(source, target, true);
Console.WriteLine(File.GetLastWriteTime(source).ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
Console.WriteLine(File.GetLastWriteTime(target).ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

The first time this is run we get:

```
17:29:01.618 (source)
00:00:00.000 (target doesn't exist yet)
17:29:01.618 (source unchanged)
17:29:01.618 (target as source)
```

On the second run:

```
17:29:01.618 (source unchanged)
17:29:01.000 (target has been rounded down)
17:29:01.618 (source unchanged)
17:29:01.618 (target as source again)
```

The the third and subsequent runs:

```
17:29:01.618 (source unchanged)
17:29:01.000 (target still as source - no rounding down)
17:29:01.618 (source unchanged)
17:29:01.618 (target as source)
```

**Update:**

Procmon shows Dropbox.exe doing a SetBasicInformationFile operation about three seconds after the initial copy, which appears to be when the change happens, although Procmon doesn't show the file time down to the millisecond.

As it only seems to affect graphic files I assume it's something to do with Dropbox thumbnail generation, but I can't really see any good reason for them to do this, especially as they leave the timestamp intact the next time it's copied.

Comment: Are you using the Dropbox API? Or just moving files around on the local filesystem? If the latter, I'm not sure there's really a programming question here.

Comment: Why would it be any less a programming question for targeting the file system rather than an API? I'll grant it is on the fringes regardless. Anyway, it is the filesystem, as described in the question.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi @Plutonix, that's interesting, but if it's supposed to contain anything which helps with the question, I'm missing it.

Comment: *`For example, the resolution of create time on FAT is 10 milliseconds, while write time has a resolution of 2 seconds and access time has a resolution of 1 day, so it is really the access date. `*

Comment: I see @Plutonix, well in that case I should clarify it's NTFS. The times are correctly recorded with millisecond resolution, but are being rounded down after the fact by dropbox some how.

Comment: Just to better understand your question, this is a script which you run manually right? And the copied file is only by milliseconds older than the original if it is copied instantly after creating it? So it is a theoretical problem which you would like to understand?

Comment: Another question, did you try to change your script to another folder which is not synced by DropBox to confirm if it is a DropBox issue or a general File.Copy issue?

Comment: Hi @dustinmoris. The script is scheduled and the copied file is made older than the source by up to 999 milliseconds, but not quite  instantaneously, presumably as part of some inappropriate behavior by the Dropbox syncing.  I wish to understand the theory but it's also causing a practical inconvenience. It does only affect the Dropbox folder yes. I've updated the question with some demo code.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that when you copy the files into the Dropbox watch folder, the Dropbox background sync app will then upload the files to Dropbox.  After doing this it then does a sync again to get the local file times the same as the uploaded ones.  Have a fiddler session running the next time and see if you get a download from Dropbox after the upload.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in Fiddler. Yes, I'm assuming it's being caused by the Dropbox syncing, but I can't see any reason it should behave in this way.

Comment: Try disabling the sync app and watch the new files while you turn it back on.  It actually might be the local app that is touching the files to update the modified time stamp.  You might want to change the script to add a file compare if the dates are less than a second difference.

Comment: If I pause syncing the date remains untouched. When I resume syncing the date is rounded down immediately before it reaches 'Up to date' status.

Comment: This sounds like a planned design by the dropbox team.  They most likely do that so they only have to worry about changes every second.  You will either have to live with it or add in the file comparing.

Comment: use PROCMON to see if its writing back

Comment: I'm starting to think it's an oversight or at least shortcoming @Brian, not a plan, at least not a very good one, as it wouldn't explain why it only happens for some file types and only for the first time it's copied in.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, based on this bit

> I've got a little C# script I use to backup my development folder to
>   my Dropbox folder

Have you thought about using the archive bit? when the file changes it will get SET and you UNSET it when you copy the file. (You is your code, UNSET the bit once you have done your BACKUP)

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_bit

Also, what about ROBOCOPY?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy

It might just work for you, no code needed.. well no c# code

```
ROBOCOPY C:\SOURCE C:\DEST /M /S
```

> /M : like /A, but remove Archive attribute from source files.

And one more :) You could CRC check the files? that will be more time consuming though.

If you want to find out WHY the file datetime is changing then use PROCMON to see if DROPBOX is changing this, could be timezone thing, could be just a thing it does.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the Procmon suggestion. It does appear to confirm Dropbox is changing this file, as I could only assume. I'm left to wonder why though, as I do want to use the last modified date in my case, rather than the archive bit or a crc check.